# kCATransitionPush applied to slide in/out image from UIImageview without fade/transparent effects iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView on the screen at some position:

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"food"];
[self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , (self.view.frame.size.width/5), 60)];
```

I had to then slide in another image inside the UIImageView which I did with the following code:

```
self.imageView.image = NULL;
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDuration:0.75];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        animation.delegate = self;
        [[self.imageView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

But when the first image slides out it fades out (or appears to be transparent towards the edge of the imageView). I tried as many of the online solutions I could find like setting the layer properties during the animation to remove the fade or assign the layer opacity to 1.0 but none of them seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different approach using another image-view and `UIView` animations:

```
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
imageView.frame = self.imageView.frame;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-imageView.frame.size.width, 0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^()
{
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    self.imageView.image = newImage;
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```